# Bars centered between the grid lines with the label below the grid lines (chart.js)

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, ng2-charts

I want to create a bar chart where the bars are centered between the grid lines.
This behaviour was possible before this merge request:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4545

In the original version this was possible with offsetGridLines: false (category scale).

I created a stackblitz with a angular app using chart.js and ng2-charts:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-barchart-example-mg192a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbarchart%2Fbarchart.ts

Working Code with chart.js 2.6.0:

```
  public barChartOptions:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    responsive: true,
        scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true,
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
```

Results in a bar chart like I want it to be (only the bars could still be centered between the grid lines):
[image]

In the current version of Chart.js (I'm currently using 2.9.3) the bars are arranged to the right and left of the grid lines:
[image]

Does the new version of chart.js offer the possibility to center the bars between the gridlines?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define `categoryPercentage: 1` for both datasets.

```
public barChartData:any[] = [
  {
    data: [55, 60, 75, 82, 56, 62, 80], 
    label: 'Company A',
    categoryPercentage: 1,
  },
  { data: [58, 55, 60, 79, 66, 57, 90], 
    label: 'Company B',
    categoryPercentage: 1,
  }
];
```

> [`categoryPercentage`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-configuration) (default 0.8): Percent (0-1) of the available width each category should be within the sample width. [more...](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barpercentage-vs-categorypercentage)

Chart.js however still won't properly layout the bars if some of them are not contained in the visible area. Therefore you'll also have to make sure that all bars are shown in the chart by defining an appropriate value for [`yAxis.ticks.min`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration).

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    min: 50
  }
}]
```

Please have a look at your amended code in the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-centered-bars-multiple-datasets?file=src/app/barchart/barchart.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). I guess the question was not asked very well. What bothers me, is that in the current version, the bars are displayed to the right and left of the grid line. But I want the bars between the grid lines to be displayed for one year, with the year label being displayed below the corresponding grid line. So just as shown in the first screenshot.